# How to add touch to jQuery slider field?

Tags: javascript

I am on Drupal 7 using the sliderfield module (https://www.drupal.org/project/sliderfield)

I want the field to be mobile and touch friendly.

The module recommends using the Jquery UI Touch Punch module to solve this (https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_touchpunch/issues/2797477) however it is not working.

Can anyone recommend an approach that will work with step by step examples?

An example could include adding code to a custom theme that can work without using the above referenced module.

Comment: I wanted to vote to close this question, but I couldn't because there is an open bounty. I think this question is off-topic because it asks for step-by-stel instructions without showing much effort. Also, it is primarily about combining two jQuery plugins, so I'm not sure if Drupal Answers is the best place to ask.

Comment: I disagree - I have installed the Drupal modules to achieve the functionality, applied the patches listed in the module issue queue, submitted a report that they did not work, and then created a stack exchange discussion for how to achieve the functionality. Please tell me what I could do other than solving it myself? The second module, Jquery Touch Punch is listed as being a solution for offering this functionality, but is currently non-functional, I am looking for help to either apply the patch listed or implement a theme specific version. Anyone who uses the module in 2018 will need this.

Comment: Exactly. The [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says questions should not be about "Issues found in existing modules/themes". Also, questions should not be "Requests for writing code from scratch", which comes pretty close to your "step by step examples" and the fact that you're not interested in solving it yourself.

Now don't get me wrong - I understand your frustration when things don't work as they should. You are just trying to solve your problem and I respect that. I just think this discussion belongs in the drupal.org issue queues instead of here.

Comment: Sure, we can delete it if it's really off topic. I'm completely interested in solving it myself, I even picked up an extra programming class so I won't have to take abuse in issue queues.

Comment: If you’re getting abuse in issue queues please report it to the website team, no one wants that. This is indeed off topic here though (for reasons already mentioned) and should be picked up in the issue queue

Comment: How would you rephrase my question in a way that would be accepted? I spent many hours on this and No Sssweat's answer worked, with modification.

Comment: @Clive  You owe me +50 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Bendev's comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_touchpunch/issues/2797477#comment-11777727)

1) Install [libraries](https://www.drupal.org/project/libraries) module

2) In sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/**template.php** 
add the following:

```
function YOUR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = libraries_get_path('jquery.ui.touch-punch') . '/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js';
}
```

<sub>Replace YOUR_THEME with the actual name of your theme.</sub>

3) Clear/Flush all caches.

Comment: Tried - receive:

"Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in /../template.php on line 29"

Comment: @Zachary did you copy the code correctly? particularly this part `&$form, &$form_state, $form_id`

Comment: I copied and pasted it and replaced my theme name in the form_alter. Maybe the paste didn't work? I can hand type and try...

Comment: this code worked: 


function YOUR_THEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#attached']['js'][] = libraries_get_path('jquery.ui.touch-punch') . '/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js';
}

Comment: I tried this in theme (bootstrap), it gives error: `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare bootstrap_form_alter() (previously declared in /public_html/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/template.php:74) in /public_html/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/includes/alter.inc on line 320`
so I added inside `bootstrap_form_alter` function in alter.inc file, but it doesn't work too :(

Comment: @RamiSedhom I imagine you flushed the cache? "View page source" with your browser to see if indeed it's not being loaded.

Comment: Yes I flushed the cache and ensured it's loaded from the page source.

Comment: I downloaded HTML Inspector for mobile browser and it seems it's not loaded on mobile although it's loaded on desktop browser!! Trying to find a solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a module to be able to create a slider field to fix the blocker of not having a standard field type "slider".

In order to be able to do it, you can [programmatically create a field](https://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2013-08-14/drupal-7-field-api) using the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range).

This can be done through the following process:

1. Add the slider library;
2. Select a field name;
3. Make sure the field doesn't exist;
4. Define / create the field;
5. Create the instance;

////See the code

```
drupal_add_library('ui.slider');
/**
 * Update hook to add a field to a node.
 */
function my_module_update_7000() {
  $field_name = 'field_slider';
  // Make sure the field doesn't already exist.
  if (!field_info_field($field_name)) {
    // Create the field.
    $field['#attached']['js'] = array(
        'field_name' => $field_name,
        "jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('#my-element').slider(); });" => array(
            'type' => 'inline'
        )
    );
    field_create_field($field);

    // Create the instance.
    $instance = array( 'field_name' => $field_name,
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => 'article',
      'label' => 'Slider',
      'description' => 'The article slider.',
      'required' => TRUE,
    );
    field_create_instance($instance);

    watchdog('my_module', t('!field_name was added successfully.', array('!field_name' => $field_name)));
  }
  else {
    watchdog('my_module', t('!field_name already exists.', array('!field_name' => $field_name)));
  }
}
```

**To note:** Replace in the instance `'bundle' => 'article',` with the name of the content type you want it attached to. In this example is adding the field to the *Article* content type.